# How can I set up a default powershell profile for all my co workers at work as simple as possible?

Tags: powershell, powershell-module

**What do I want to achieve?**

I have one ps1 file that has all of my functions inside. In the first step I want to convert it into a ps module. Then I want to have the following:

- Colleague gets a script or bat he has to run ONCE. This will set his Modules Environment path `$Env:PSModulePath` to a path on a network drive everyone has access to
- Copy and paste a custom profile.ps1 into the users `%userprofile%\Documents\WindowsPowershell` that imports the module
- Every user should now have the powershell scripts I made available in their shell

**How I tried to solve it**

The way me and a colleague have set it up in the past is with this:

(we have a `profile.ps1` file that does the following):

```
#set path for profile_loader.ps1
$path = "\\server\share\folderwithscripts";
#call profile_loader.ps1
. "$path"
```

Then this `profile_loader.ps1` baiscally just loads tons of scripts (ps1 files) like this:

`. "\\server\share\pathtoanotherscript.ps1`

Line after line.

I don't like it and it is too complicated for my 25 other colleagues I want to set up in the future.

**Question**

*What is the best way to achieve this? A good old .bat file that copy and past the ps1 file into their userprofile? Or is there a better way?*

Comment: If this is just so your colleagues can get a module you created, then how about setting up [your own PowerShellGet server](https://redmondmag.com/articles/2016/12/23/internal-nuget-repository-in-powershell.aspx)?  That way, they can install any modules you publish, and easily get updates.  More work up-front, but no need to mess about with file shares and batch scripts, and will scale better as you add users and modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone who had their `$profile` wiped and set to a "company default", for the love of god, don't.

If you have to, then I suggest just creating a profile you want everyone to have with all your modules in a shared location, like your securely locked down Sysadmin folder.

Do `psedit $proile.AllUsersAllHosts` on your machine, modify that, then make a text file with all the hostnames you want to destroy with your own forced profile. Throw this in there to make it import your modules by default.

```
# Checks your server share for any PSM1 files, could change to include PS1 as well I suppose. Long name because its in a $Profile so ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
$ModulePathWithLongNameBecauseSomeoneMayUseThisInAnActualScript = Get-ChildItem -file -Recurse "\\server\share\" -Include "*.psm1"
# Sets module path for other adhoc module calls if they dont want to restart their Powershell
$env:PSModulePath = $env:PSModulePath + ";\\server\share\"

# Imports all PSM1 files from the ModulePath*
Foreach($psm in $ModulePathWithLongNameBecauseSomeoneMayUseThisInAnActualScript){
    Import-Module "$($ModulePath.FullName)"
}
```

Run this on your machine to deliver your soul crushing `$profile` to your colleagues who may have had their own setup.

```
# Get a list of machines that your staff will use and throw them into a txt or csv etc.
$PCsForForcedProfile = Get-Content "\\server\share\PleaseNo.txt"
Foreach($Colleague in $PCsForForcedProfile){
    Copy-Item "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1" "\\$Colleague\C$\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\" -force
}
```

Comment: That is just perfect. Thank you so much. I will accept this question.